# Accessing fields from inner query

Tags: soql, query

Below is my query

```
SELECT id,(SELECT id,ServiceResourceId, ServiceAppointmentId FROM
   ServiceResources), ParentRecordId  FROM serviceappointment
```

This is the result of what it looks like in the dev console[image]

How can I access the fields from the "serviceresources" section?

Service resources is the detail of the master serviceappointment

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Where are you trying to access the subquery results from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lest say you want to access the first name of Contacts from the parent Account object. So to access these values you can do something like this:

```
List<Account> listAcc =[SELECT Name, 
                            (SELECT FirstName, LastName 
                                   FROM Contacts) FROM Account]; 
for(Account a: listAcc)
{
    for(Contact c: a.Contacts)
    {
        system.debug('This is the first name: ' + c.FirstName); 
    }
}
```

This is the way to can access inner values for related objects. You can run that code in your developer console and it will print out all **FirstNames** for the contacts.